# Change /tmp folder for jenkins in debian

Tags: jenkins, debian, tmp

[image]I recently had a low disc space issue in jenkins. Although the home directory has sufficient space, the /tmp did not and it brought my master down.

I tried many ways to fix this

1. Discard old build and deleting old workspaces
2. Restarting jenkins
3. Tried to setup a node with same config and starting it, but that failed saying i dont have sufficient permission for copying remote.jar

Since my server is debian, I could not find any file where I could set set -Djava.io.tmpdir
Many people talked about jenkin file or config file, but I could not find it.

The only thing that worked was https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/tmpcleaner/ , this plugin hpi, which I installed through Advanced tag in plugins.

Also, I went manually to the /tmp folder in root and then deleted it contents to start the jenkins again. So my question is:

1. How do i change the /tmp folder in jenkins?
2. The jenkins home directory is /mnt/data/jenkins, however the tmp it uses it root/tmp. Why is it so? The /mnt/data/jenkins has lots of free space and i manually created a /tmp folder there, but it only takes the /tmp from the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague found the answer out

1. open '/etc/defaults/jenkins'  file using command 'less /etc/defaults/jenkins'
2. Add argument

JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -Djava.io.tmpdir=yourNewtempLocation"

Once you restart jenkins, you will be able to see the storage of the new space